# Blackberry Application Development

Tags: blackberry, dictionary

i am developing an app for blackberry and i am using blackberry maps in it. but when i am invoking the maps, getting an exception suspended (EOF exception). and on console 
NO DENTRY KEY FOUND (0xeeeeeeee)!!

Comment: Can you view the BB Maps application on its own? Do you have the MDS Simulator running?

Comment: i am surprised,, why i didn't check it. its not working on its own in my simulator. but why so i dont know while MDS was running...
Can you please tell me what should i do now....
Thanks ......

Comment: Maybe you need to switch on the WLAN/3G/whatever connection in simulator?

Comment: Did you make sure to start the MDS simulator before running the actual simulator? I've found that some of them will not respond to the fact that it's on if you don't let it go through the complete startup process before launching the device simulator.

Comment: yes i started the MDS simulator before running the actual simulator but still it is not working. i am using 9800 simulator. here i also want to mention  that when i checked my bb maps in all programs in simulator instead via my application ...the same error i found... NO DENTRY KEY FOUND (0xeeeeeeee)!!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working in the latest 9800 simulator I was able to download from RIM: **6.0.0.534**

In the 9800 simulator that was bundled with the OS6 eclipse plugin, I got the exact same error as mentioned above (NO DENTRY KEY FOUND (0xeeeeeeee)).

Good luck!